# I want to prevent the Checkout button from working until checkbox is checked. They can checkout without clicking terms and conditions checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to prevent the Checkout button from working until checkbox is checked. They can checkout without clicking terms and conditions checkbox

```
<!--Beginning jQuery !-->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery('#checkoutButton').unbind('click');  
jQuery("#checkoutButton").click(function(event)
jQuery('#checkoutButtonDup').unbind('click');  
jQuery("#checkoutButtonDup").click(function(event)
{  

event.preventDefault();   
if (jQuery("#TermsandConditions").val() == ""){  
         alert("Please check Terms of Use checkbox");  
         return false;  

    } else {  
         Infusion.ManageCart.submitForm('oneStepCheckout', true, 0, 0);  
         return true;  
    }  
    });
});
</script>
<!--End of jQuery!-->
<!--Beginning of checkbox TermsandConditions!-->
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="TermsandConditions" name="TermsandConditions"/>
  <label for="TermsandConditions" class='ff-label' style='display:inline; color:#990000'><strong>I have read and agree to the Terms of Use.</strong></label>
</div>
<!--End of checkbox TermsandConditions!-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSFiddle which removes the disabled attribute.  You could extend this if you wanted to just add/remove disabled on the button based on the checkbox status:

```
$(function(){
    $("#cb").on('click',function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $("#btn").removeAttr("disabled");   
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I have to go live with this by close of business today... Is there any way that you would be available to help troubleshoot via screen share. I will pay via Paypal or whatever is convenient if you can help. It's within a form in a checkout program for Infusionsoft which is a CRM system. This seems like it would work, but I am an extreme novice my specialty is Government Consulting not java so I am not even sure how to implement these changes. lol Thanks... lol

Comment: I might be able to help, but have to run out this morning.  If the form itself isn't too sensitive, throw it up on jsfiddle.net, or send a link to the source using Google Docs (for just that form) and it might be quick and easy to get working.

Comment: Ok, try this...it's about as simple as it gets...all the js inline so you don't have to worry about anything...

In the 'div' tag is the checkbox.  Below that is the submit button.  The id of the submit button is important (currently called 'submitButton').  

http://jsfiddle.net/3v5jF/3/

Comment: That is by far the simplest I have seen and when I tested it, it doesn't work. I made sure to change the name in the coding to the proper name of #checkoutButton and still no luck. Here is a form if you have time to see what is happening. Again I will be happy to pay for your time today. http://goo.gl/UbR61m

Comment: Your 'button' in this case is a link (anchor tag) which doesn't do anything anyhow.  I'll try to rewrite it to work with a link.

Comment: We went with a work around no worries. I really appreciate you helping out. The coding works with order forms, but it wouldn't work in the shopping cart theme the CRM makes us use. So we are disabling the shopping cart feature and just doing check out by product and bundles. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it going and sorry the solution wasn't plug-n-play.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ..

The jquery's `.is()` and `:checked` can make it really simple

here's a the demo
[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7KEsz/1/)

Comment: I have to go live with this by close of business today... Is there any way that you would be available to help troubleshoot via screen share. I will pay via Paypal or whatever is convenient if you can help. It's within a form in a checkout program for Infusionsoft which is a CRM system. This seems like it would work, but I am an extreme novice my specialty is Government Consulting not java so I am not even sure how to implement these changes. Thanks... lol